# Providing Dynamic Type for content of Table View

Tags: ios

I am trying to make content of a Table View to be able to change its font size, if user did select another font size in his iPhone settings. I managed to achieve it by putting the following code:

```
//(Start)Updating font size
UIFont *font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
cell.textLabel.font = font;
//(END)
```

But it doesn't update the content of a Table View automatically and I need to make a click on it to perform changes. I am pretty sure that my solution isn't the right one, so could you help out by telling what is a proper way to achieve my goal.

Here is the full code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString * kGroupsTableViewCell = @"kGroupsTableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kGroupsTableViewCell];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kGroupsTableViewCell];
}

TGroup * group = [self.groupsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = group.name;

//(Start)Updating font size
UIFont *font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
cell.textLabel.font = font;
//(END)

if ([self.selectedGroups containsObject:group.uid]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to subscribe to the size change notifications and reload the table.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self.tableView
      selector:@selector(reloadData)
          name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification
        object:nil];
}
- (void)dealloc
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.tableView];
}
```